use "by rememberSaveable" with map
I'm used to declaring state vars in compose using by Saveable, but if you use it for a map it returns the map's value instead of a stateful map.  Is there an equivalent in compose or do I need to move my MutableStateMap to my viewmodel to keep map state?
var tempFilters by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateMapOf(
            Pair(Filter.APPROVED, false),
            Pair(Filter.REJECTED, false),
            Pair(Filter.WAITING, false)
        )
    }


You don't need the by keyword to directly modify the SnapShotStateMap returned by mutableStateMapOf(). Please try the following code:
val tempFilters = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf(
        Pair(Filter.APPROVED, false),
        Pair(Filter.REJECTED, false),
        Pair(Filter.WAITING, false)
    )
}

tempFilters["NEW KEY"] = true  // when key not exists, it will be added to the Map
tempFilters[Filter.WAITING] = true  // when key already exists, its value will be updated

If you make any changes using this code, Jetpack will trigger a recomposition.
Also note that rememberSaveable is not available out of the box for SnapshotStateMaps, you would need to implement a custom save handle or delegate it to a ViewModel to persist the Map across configuration changes.

Background
When you use the by keyword together with a regular mutableStateOf(), you can see in Android Studio that by refers to the function
    var mutableString by remember {  // uses androidx.compose.runtime.getValue()
        mutableStateOf("APPROVED") 
    }

which is applicable to any types that implement the State<T>. It is implemented to return the value property.
However, when you use the by keyword with a veriable of type SnapshotStateMap which is returned by mutableStateMapOf(), then Kotlin will actually use another getValue() function:
var tempFilters by rememberSaveable {  // uses  kotlin.collections.getValue()
    mutableStateMapOf(
        //...
    )
}

This is implemented as follows:
public inline operator fun <V, V1 : V> MutableMap<in String, out @Exact V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V1 =
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (getOrImplicitDefault(property.name) as V1)

It returns

the value for the key, or
a default value if it was provided to the Map using withDefault, or
it will throw an NoSuchElementException.

So the by keyword for SnapShotStateMap is not what you are looking for in that case.
